# Avoid margin of the first page - printing

Tags: javascript, css, html, printing

I'm trying to avoid the margin of the first page. All tables (there are many) are fitting a page. But the first one has a margin.

I tried: so many ways. Is there a way with CSS to avoid margin on first page? I tried on body, html, page...

I've searching a lot. But I can't find a solution. I though of creating an element and put it on the first page.

My page has many tables. One per page. Except the first one fits on one page due to the margin.

```
@media print {
@page {
        margin: 0mm;
        size: auto;
        padding: 0;
}

@page:first {
        margin: 0px;         
        color:blue;    
    }   


html {
        margin: 0px;
}


body {
        display: table;
        margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; /* margin you want for the content */   
        margin-top:0px !important;
}

.tableSchedule tr {
        padding-top: 0px;
        height:45px;

        }
.tableSchedule {
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:1130px;
        margin:0;        
        page-break-after:always;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with images and divs in the past. Turns out that even if you set the margin to 0 some browsers will seperate elements, particularly inline elements, with a space of 1 em. Setting the font-size: 0 for the parent element removed that "phantom" margin. Just don't forget to change the font size back for the child elements!

Alternatively you can style the first table with a negative margin to cheat. i.e. margin-left: -15px . Or so depending on your needs.